# Google App Engine Flex on running Play Framework app getting No X11 DISPLAY variable was set error ; where do I set this variable?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, playframework, google-api

I am running an application (Play Framework) on the Google App Engine Flex environment, that is trying to download a file from the Google Drive.  When I attempt to download the code, I receive this error:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:142)
```

I found a few posts on what is happening but nothing to help me with the Google App Engine Flex and Play Framework:

["No X11 DISPLAY variable" - what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean)

[Start X server on Google Cloud (Debian) Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562860/start-x-server-on-google-cloud-debian-compute-engine)

Here is my code that I am using:

```
public static void downloadFile(String fileID) {
    // Set the drive service...
    Drive service = null;
    try {
        service = getDriveService();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
        // place your webContentLink in the oURL variable
        URI oURL = new URI("https://drive.google.com/a/google.com/uc?id=" + fileID + "&export=download");
        desktop.browse(oURL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

which came from this post:

[How to force download of file from Google Team Drive using Google Drive API libraries in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071968/how-to-force-download-of-file-from-google-team-drive-using-google-drive-api-libr/51168565#51168565)

I see that, from this post, that I may need to set a variable `DISPLAY=0:0`:

https://superuser.com/questions/1223939/no-x11-display-variable-was-set-but-this-program-performed-an-operation-which-r

How do I set this variable inside the Play Framework application or can I set on the Google App Engine Flex instance?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/reference/app-yaml#defining_environment_variables) in App Engine flexible. So, in your case, try to edit your `app.yaml` file like this:

```
env_variables:
    DISPLAY=0.0
```